# How to download files in a moodle course using R?

Tags: r, moodle, rvest, httr

There is a moodle course with files that I wish to download automatically. I see that there is a [python solution](https://github.com/vinaychandra/Moodle-Downloader) for doing so, but I couldn't find an R solution. I am not sure which package and what type of workflow would fit here (I assume some combination of httr and rvest). Any suggestion would be appreciated.

The first problem is how to deal with the authentication of moodle. In my case, I need 3 items (personal id, user name, and password).

From a google search I was able to find the following moodle related packages (non seem to help): [SARP.moodle](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SARP.moodle/index.html), [moodler](https://github.com/jchrom/moodler). Using download.file on the homepage of the course only redirects to the page viewed by people who do not have access to the course. No pop-up window shows for entering passwords (and again, in my case there is a need for 3 items of the password).

Comment: I see a downvote, but no explanation on what is missing from the question.

Comment: See `?download.file`.

Comment: I have no idea how to deal with the authentication of moodle using download.file. Do you?

Comment: @MrFlick I updated the question with more details of the issue I'm facing.

Comment: This question still reads like "please translate this python script into R for me" which are not the type of "questions" that are welcome here. You should provide the documentation necessary to know what's really required. If usernames and passwords are required to make this work, it's going to be difficult to help you. It's unclear what your input is even to identify files.